# Issue with all the window icons

Tags: windows, icons, shortcut-file

I was opening dreamweaver file. it opened open with option i check the dreamweaver and didnt noticed that always open this type of file was checked, now all the .lnk extension files changed to dreamweaver. i cant open any shortcut. please help me solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the registry is changed. I have been having this problem myself before and I had to download a .reg file that fixed the issue.

[Windows 7, 8 and Vista(This downloads a .txt file possibly, remove file extension .txt and leave the .reg extension): Click Here.](http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/tutorials/159134d1312706820-default-file-type-associations-restore-default_lnk_-shortcut-.reg)

[Windows XP: Click here.](http://www.dougknox.com/xp/fileassoc/linkfile_fix.zip)

You can fix this yourself in the registry editor by doing the following:
Click Start Menu, and then type regedit in the Start Search and press ENTER.
Browse to the following registry branch:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.lnk
Click on the arrow to expand it and delete the sub-key named UserChoice.
Exit from Registry Editor and reboot your machine.